# Unsure how .join() functions with two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, join

In the following method, I am unsure of what **.join(data_directory, d)** and **.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrafficSigns/Training")** yields.  Specifically I don't know how .join() handles these two parameters.

```
def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) 
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

ROOT_PATH = "/your/root/path"
train_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrafficSigns/Training")
test_data_directory = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrafficSigns/Testing")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_directory)
```

A quick note, I am loading images from within the TrafficSign folder (which contains the two folders, Training and Testing).

Comment: Keep in mind that this is [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), not `str.join`.  `os.path.join` takes one or more paths and joins them together using `os.sep`

Comment: but why include both the **data_directory** and **d** in the parameters? Why not only have _**d**_ as a parameter?  What is the significance of having both of them and how do they interact?

Comment: `data_directory` is some directory, say `/path/to/`.  `listdir(data_directory)` is an iterable of all of the things in that directory (files, other directories, etc.). So `path.join(data_directory, d)` is just the full path to something in `data_directory`.  Say there is some file `file`.  Then `d` is `'file'`, `data_directory` is `'/path/to/'`, and `path.join(data_directory, file)` is `/path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.join()`

This safely joins the paths together as a string.  It uses `os.sep` to ensure the correct path separator is used for the os platform.  It can correct extra separators.

```
mypath = os.path.join("/some/path/", "/directory")
print(mypath) # "/some/path/directory"
```